# Multiplication, Division and Parenthesis

Tags: arithmetic, associativity

Considering the arithmetic expression: $8/2(4)$

Is the answer simplified to be:

$(8) / (2*4) = 1$

or is it:

$(8/2) * (4) = 16$?

Please, explain why with your answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2966916/is-9-41-not-equal-to-4?rq=1

Comment: Also cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310832/why-does-the-calculation-formula-for-8-2-22-have-changed#comment6811697_3310832)

Comment: https://m.huffingtonpost.ca/entry/math-problem-twitter-bedmas-pemdas_ca_5d420367e4b0acb57fc6b0fd#comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$8/2(4)$

Considering BODMAS, lets begin with the Bracket (B). That is,

$8/2(4) = 8/2 × 4$ -- (1)

From the RHS of (1), we evaluate further via Division (D). That is,

$8/2 × 4 = 4 × 4$ -- (2)

From the RHS of (2), we conclude the simplification via Multiplication (M). That is,

$4 × 4 = 16$ ...Ans.

Comment: Thank you for referencing BODMAS, which led me to research it and PEDMAS and finally understand the answer.

Comment: @SamElie, you're welcome!

Comment: But this begs the question, why should it be PEDMAS and not PEMDAS?

Comment: @NikiDiGiano I believe you are correct. It is PEMDAS.

Comment: And then if M stands for multiplication and D for division, why would one do the division first? ;)

Comment: @NikiDiGiano, when it entails exponent in computing, one is advised to go with PEDMAS but in Mathematics, you make use of PEDMAS. Since the question Sam-Elie posted has nothing to do with exponent, BODMAS is a better abbreviated term for the order of operations to be used. You can read more on this via: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather weird way to express $\frac{8}{2} \cdot 4.$ As it is written, it represents the second option (which is 16).

**ANSWER TO COMMENT:** The parentesis takes precedence, but there are no operations to do in it! It's just a 4. So after you're done with the operations in the parenthesis, you begin to make the division/multiplication from left to right.

Comment: Could you please explain why? and why do you think the parenthesis does not take precedence ?

Comment: By left to right logic: Multiplication/division require two operands. One to the left, and one to the right. reading from left: first operation is division, left operand is 8 and right operand is 2 *4, which yields 1. don't you think ?

Comment: No. Left operand is $8$ and right operand is $2$. Then you multiply the result by $4$. Otherwise you would be operating from right to left (making the right-most operation first)

Comment: Okay, makes sense, but what about the parenthesis precedence, and i'm not talking about what's inside, i'm talking about the 2 on the outside which could or could not be considered a factor of the same operation as (4). Like in junior math, * is more powerful than +, why is ( not more powerful than / ? (notice i asked about parenthesis only not "*(" )

Comment: "Parenthesis precedence" means that you should do first what's INSIDE the parenthesis. For example, $3 \cdot 2 + (3+5)=14$ rather than $19$. Multiplication and division (which is itself ultimately just multiplication, you could write your expression as $8 \frac{1}{2} (4)=16)$ have the same order of preference (both going behind addition)  This is a conventeion, there is no particular reason for it, and it could have been defined any other way, but this is what mathematicians have sticked to for centuries

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those cases that go viral on the Internet because people can't agree on a convention.
The reason why we need a convention is because *division is not associative, in particular division and multiplication are not compatible associatively*. In the language of abstract algebra, the *taking inverse* and *multiplication by an element* functions do not commute.

As such, an epression of the form:
$$
x = x_1 \circ_1 x_2 \circ_2 \ldots \circ_{n-1} x_n
$$
Where any of the $\circ_i$ operations are non-associative, is not well defined for general operations $\circ_i$ unless we use parenthesis.

The problem is how we are going to group a series of non-associative operations. For this example I will only use one non-associative operation but the same applies to many. *If* your convention is:
$$
\prod_i x_i = (((x_1 \circ x_2)x_3)\ldots)x_n
$$
Then the answer is $16$. If the convention is:
$$
\prod_i x_i = x_1(x_2(x_3\ldots(x_{n-1} \circ x_n)))
$$
Then the answer is $1$. In standard mathematics we went with the first convention. So the answer that makes most sense in this context is $16$.

Also because starting with the last operation in a string of operations that, for example, might be the result of a limiting process (i.e. infinite series, the string is infinite), is kinda convoluted.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense, as well as lends validity to @David 's answer.

Comment: This started out well, but the claim that the string of $\circ$s is *never* well-defined is too stong. In the case of a string of $+$ and $-$ the lack of associativity is the same, but there is a universally observed convrntion for what it means nevertheless.

Comment: How exactly would it be universal? $4 - 2 + (2+2)$ has the same exact problems as the multiplication one. It's just habit. You always already assume the first convention on sums and subtractions instinctually, and for some reason some might get confused with multiplication and division. Unless there is something specific to sums that makes the first convention necessary, which I would have to ask you a proof of.